# Best practice: creating browser Activity or calling ACTION_VIEW Intent?

Tags: android

My app has lots of URLs the user can click on and I've created a browser-like Activty using a WebView and WebClient.  But I've found I have to maintain this and set many different settings as the web evolves like HTML5's Web Storage APIs, etc.  I'm thinking about just invoking an ACTION_VIEW intent so the user can just launch everything in their preferred browser.

What would be the pros and cons of doing this?  I'm a relatively new Android developer so I'm not totally sure about the task stacks and how these two approaches would work differently in regards to that.  I'm mostly concerned about the user leaving my app, and then not being able to get back to where they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your own web view inside application

**Pros:**
You would be able to handle all the java script alerts like "ok", "ok-cancel", "ok-confirm" from your web view client.

**Cons:**
You have to do many customization or add features in web view for rendering different kind of websites.